# auth0 custom database script that gets users gelocation on sign up

Tags: mysql, database

Hello I am working on the sign up and login functionality in a  xamarin forms app that connects to a auth0 custom database. What I need it to do is  when the user signs up for a account I want the current geolocation of that user saved to my auth0 database along with the email,address,password, first name, last name, and stage name of the user. this is how my auth0 custom database script looks now:

```
function create (user, callback) {
  // This script should create a user entry in your existing database. It will
  // be executed when a user attempts to sign up, or when a user is created
  // through the Auth0 dashboard or API.
  // When this script has finished executing, the Login script will be
  // executed immediately afterwards, to verify that the user was created
  // successfully.
  //
  // The user object will always contain the following properties:
  // * email: the user's email
  // * password: the password entered by the user, in plain text
  // * tenant: the name of this Auth0 account
  // * client_id: the client ID of the application where the user signed up, or
  //              API key if created through the API or Auth0 dashboard
  // * connection: the name of this database connection
  //
  // There are three ways this script can finish:
  // 1. A user was successfully created
  //     callback(null);
  // 2. This user already exists in your database
  //     callback(new ValidationError("user_exists", "my error message"));
  // 3. Something went wrong while trying to reach your database
  //     callback(new Error("my error message"));

  var msg = "Please implement the Create script for this database connection "
      + "at https://manage.auth0.com/#/connections/database";
  return callback(new Error(msg));
}
```

any help would be amazing!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What have you tried? And what's not working?

Comment: @hichame.yessou I am new to mysql so I haven't really tried anything do you have any suggestions on how I to go about making the script to store current geolocation, email address, password, and stage name? Please let me know? and thank you for the fast reply :)

Comment: I think you should first integrate and implement auth0 in a Xamarin.Forms app. Then you will handle the geolocalization of the login of the user at an app level (check out Xam.Plugin.Geolocator by James Montemagno) and not with MySQL

Comment: @hichame.yessou the reason I need the gelocation stored in the database is because I'm going to be displaying user profiles that are in a cretin range of the user searching the user profiles so with that being said storing the users geolocation upon sign up is the only way I know to go so can you please share with me a way to store the geolocation in the database upon user sign up? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The point is that you should ask questions about a specific problem you've faced, not requirements. I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic